# defhealthindex function does not happen while loop does not execute

Tags: python

I cannot get the healthindex function to work. Even when I input b or h, nothing happens the while loop does not execute. I tried to make it so the input would make two seperate segments of code happen based on the input, but that is not happening. Thank you!

```
def inputM():
  print("Enter weight in kg")
  weightm = float(input())
  print("Enter heigh in meters")
  heightm = float(input())
  return weightm, heightm
def inputI():
  print("Enter weight in pounds")
  weighti = float(input())
  print("Enter height in inches")
  heighti = float(input())
  return weighti, heighti

def healthindex (BMIList, BMINum, bmi):
  if healthy == "b": 
    print (str(bmi))
  elif healthy == "h":
    index = 0
    print ("Your bmi is" + (str(bmi))
    while index < len(BMIList):
      if bmi < BMINum[index]:
        print ("And, you are " + BMIList[index])
        return
      index = index + 1
    print("You are Obese")
  return

BMIList = ["severly underweight", "underweight", "healthy", "overweight", "obese"]
BMINum = [12, 18.4, 24.9, 29.9, 200]
print("Welcome to BMI Calculator!")
print("Enter I for Imperial or M for Metric")
request = input().upper()

if request == "M":
  weightm, heightm = inputM()
  bmi = weightm/(heightm**2)
elif request == "I":
  weighti, heighti = inputI()
  bmi = (703*weighti)/(heighti**2)  
else:
  print("Invalid input")

print("Enter b to only see your bmi or enter h if you would like to see your bmi and health index")

healthy= input()
healthindex (BMIList, BMINum, bmi)
```

Comment: what is healthy? where is it defined?

Comment: At the very bottom. It's an input

Comment: You're missing a ')' at line 19 in the healthindex function.
It should be:
`print ("Your bmi is" + (str(bmi)))`

Answer (score 1):

You should also pass healthy variable to the healthindex function

```
healthindex (BMIList, BMINum, bmi, healthy)
```

Full code

```py
def inputM():
  print("Enter weight in kg")
  weightm = float(input())
  print("Enter heigh in meters")
  heightm = float(input())
  return weightm, heightm
def inputI():
  print("Enter weight in pounds")
  weighti = float(input())
  print("Enter height in inches")
  heighti = float(input())
  return weighti, heighti

def healthindex (BMIList, BMINum, bmi, healthy):
  if healthy == "b": 
    print (str(bmi))
  elif healthy == "h":
    index = 0
    print ("Your bmi is " + (str(bmi)))
    while index < len(BMIList):
      if bmi < BMINum[index]:
        print ("And, you are " + BMIList[index])
        return
      index = index + 1
    print("You are Obese")
  return

BMIList = ["severly underweight", "underweight", "healthy", "overweight", "obese"]
BMINum = [12, 18.4, 24.9, 29.9, 200]
print("Welcome to BMI Calculator!")
print("Enter I for Imperial or M for Metric")
request = input().upper()

if request == "M":
  weightm, heightm = inputM()
  bmi = weightm/(heightm**2)
elif request == "I":
  weighti, heighti = inputI()
  bmi = (703*weighti)/(heighti**2)  
else:
  print("Invalid input")

print("Enter b to only see your bmi or enter h if you would like to see your bmi and health index")

healthy= input()
healthindex (BMIList, BMINum, bmi, healthy)
```

Comment: I copied and pasted that in, but the code still isn't working

Comment: @Julia I have updated my code. you have forgot put one `)` in this line `print ("Your bmi is" + (str(bmi))`. It is working now. Please upvote my answer to help me also

Answer (score 0):

```
...
def healthindex (preference, bmi):
  if preference == "b": 
    print (str(bmi))
  elif preference == "h":
    index = 0
    print ("Your bmi is" + (str(bmi)))
    while index < len(BMIList):
      if bmi < BMINum[index]:
        print ("And, you are " + BMIList[index])
        return
      index = index + 1
    print("You are Obese")
  return

...
healthindex (healthy, bmi)
```

`...` refers to unchanged codes